# performant query using analytic function to select records with 2 date columns

Tags: sql, oracle10g, analytic-functions

I'm looking for a perfomant way to write a SQL query.

I've got a table with columns (`id`,`fname`,`lname`,`accountid`,`creation_date`,`update_date`) and i have to look for the records in that table that have the same `fname`,`lname`,`accountid` and have the most recent date based on `greatest(max(creation_date),max(update_date))` (note that `update_date` can be null)

I expect that I need to use analytic functions

I have these cases:

```
(id,fname,lname,accountid,creation_date,update_date)
(1,'a','a','2','07/01/2010 10:59:43','07/01/2010 10:59:43')
(2,'a','a','2','07/01/2010 10:59:43','07/01/2010 10:59:43')
(3,'a','a','2','07/01/2010 10:59:43','07/01/2010 10:59:43')
```

I want to choose the last inserted : this record (3,'a','a','2','07/01/2010 10:59:43','07/01/2010 10:59:43')

```
(id,fname,lname,accountid,creation_date,update_date)
(3,'b','a','2','07/01/2009 10:59:43','07/01/2010 10:59:43')
(4,'b','a','2','07/01/2011 10:59:43',null)
(5,'b','a','2','07/01/2009 10:59:43','07/01/2009 10:59:43')
```

I want to choose the most recent one on both columns (creation_date,update_date) which is (4,'b','a','2','07/01/201110:59:43',null)

```
(id,fname,lname,accountid,creation_date,update_date)
(6,'c','g','4','07/01/2010 10:59:43',null)
(7,'c','g','4','07/01/2011 10:59:43',null)
(8,'c','g','4','07/01/2009 10:59:43',null)
```

I want to choose the most recent one on both columns (creation_date,update_date) which is (7,'c','g','4','07/01/2011 10:59:43',null)

```
(id,fname,lname,accountid,creation_date,update_date)
(9,'k','t','2','07/01/2009 10:59:43','07/01/2012 10:59:43')
(10,'k','t','2','07/01/2011 10:59:43',null)
(11,'k','t','2','07/01/2009 10:59:43','07/01/2009 10:59:43')
```

I want to choose the most recent one on both columns (creation_date,update_date) which is 
(9,'k','t','2','07/01/2009 10:59:43','07/01/2012 10:59:43')

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question.  It would be helpful to post some sample data, the desired output, and an explanation of how you got from the sample data to the desired output.  It would be even better if you could post that in the form of the `DDL` to create the table and the `DML` to insert the sample data so we can run your code in our environment(s).

Comment: In the first set of rows, why do you choose the row with an `id` of 3 when all 6 date values appear to be identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the analytic functions [`rank()`](http://psoug.org/reference/rank.html) or [`row_number()`](http://psoug.org/snippet/ROW_NUMBER_483.htm). My own particular preference is toward `rank()` but it only really works well if are partitioning by a unique index. Something like the following, assuming there is a unique index on `fname, lname, accountid, creation_date`

```
select *
  from ( select a.*
              , rank() over ( partition by fname, lname, accountid 
                      order by creation_date desc
                              , update_date desc ) as rnk
           from my_table a )
 where rnk = 1
```

This orders each combination of `fname, lname, accountid` by `creation_date`, `update_date`. Using `where rnk = 1`, enables you to then select the maximum `creation_date, update_date`.

Comment: I've been struggling with something for a while now and your rank suggestion worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               rank() over (partition by fname, lname, accountid
                                order by coalesce( update_date, creation_date ) desc,
                                         id desc) rnk
          FROM your_table)
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

- I'm guessing a bit at why you would want the row with an `id` of 3 returned rather than the rows with an `id` of 1 or 2 since all 3 rows have the same `update_date` and `creation_date`.  My guess is that you want to pick the tie by choosing the row with the largest `id` value.  If you want to implement a different rule, you'll need to tell us what rule that is.
- I am also assuming that the `update_date`, if it exists, will always be greater than or equal to the `creation_date`.  It would be odd if a row were updated before it was created.